# Know if subprocess is not stuck by it's prints to stdout

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, stdout

I have subprocess that I am running by:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("python -u my_script.py", shell=True)
```

my_script.py should print regularly to stdout and I have other non related process that is listening to this output so I can't change the output to be printed to somewhere else.

I want to ensure that the process is really regularly printing and not got stuck in some loop .etc, do I have way to check if stdout was wroten for some amount of time?

any other options to reach this goal?

**EDIT**

I am using windows

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the access time and modification time of `/dev/stdout` is updated regularly.  Note, however, that `/dev/stdout` will *always* be a soft link -- er, a symbolic link, I mean -- to the file handle of `stdout` for the process that's checking `/dev/stdout`.  I.e., `/dev/stdout` links to `/proc/self/fd/1`.

So it seems that you could check the first file descriptor of your process to see if its modification time has changed, e.g.:

```
$ stat -c %y -L /proc/10830/fd/1
2021-05-13 02:34:00.367857061
```

`-L` means act on the target of the soft link, not the soft link itself; `-c %y` is just asking for the modification time.  This Python script is running as process 10830 on my system right now, and it's occasionally updating the modification time (about every 8 seconds):

```
>>> import time
>>> while True: time.sleep(1); print("still alive")
still alive
still alive
still alive
....
```

You should Google this answer to be sure that the behavior I'm seeing is reliable, though, because I've never read anything about it before.

Alternatively, you could either (a) trust that the script is fine -- which it will,  of course, always be (unless it's catching exceptions and refusing to exit even if it can no longer do anything useful, in which case you should change it to die the way it should), or (b) set up a daemon to do something like send a signal to the script, at which point the script could send a signal to the daemon to say "I'm still alive."  There's literally no reason to do that, in my opinion, but how you write your programs is up to you.

So assuming that you want to press forward with this, here's a trivial example of the daemon that would monitor the script you want to make sure isn't stuck in a loop or something:

```py
import time
import signal
import os
import sys

# keep a timestamp of when we receive a response
response_timestamp = time.time()

# add code here to get the process ID of the other script
other_pid = 0

def sig_handler(signum, frame):
  global response_timestamp
  response_timestamp = time.time()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # make sure that when we receive SIGBREAK, sig_handler() gets called
  signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, sig_handler)

  while True:
    # send SIGBREAK to "other_pid"
    os.kill(other_pid, signal.SIGBREAK)
    time.sleep(15)
    
    if time.time() - 20 > response_timestamp:
      print("the other process is frozen")
      sys.exit(os.EX_SOFTWARE)
```

Then you add this to the other script that you're monitoring:

```py
import signal
import os

# add code here to get the process ID
other_pid = 0

def sig_handler(signum, frame):
  os.kill(other_pid, signal.SIGBREAK)

...
...
(rest of your script)
```

Now be aware that the only thing this will do, is make sure that the process isn't completely frozen.  Regrettably, Windows doesn't have a great deal of options when it comes to signals: SIGBREAK was the best one that I saw, but note that it's the signal received by a process when you hit CTRL+C to interrupt the program (so if you manually hit CTRL+C in the window running the Python program, it won't kill it, it will just make it call `sig_handler()`).

I would also be remiss if I did not inform you that even though this will probably work just fine, *it is not safe to do almost anything inside of a signal handler function*.  It's bad form and may blow up on you unexpectedly, but in practice, it's pretty safe.

Comment: hi, dose this answer is applicable also for windows os or just linux?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't even think about that: the first portion is exclusive to *Nix systems (the `/proc` part).  Both Windows and Linux implement a form of signals, though, so that part is applicable to you.  I'll edit the answer to provide more of an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a named pipe with mkfifo and use tee to output your script's data to both the process listening for it and the pipe.

```
mkfifo blarg
my_script.py | tee blarg | your_greedy_data_processing_instance
tail -f blarg
```

instead of tail you can use an arbitrarly complicated script to study the output and the state of the process generating it (timers, pid checks)

Comment: hi, I think this is linux command and I am windows user, moreover I don't know who is the other process that need the output so I can't pipe it to him